# If $\lim_{x \to \infty} x_n=l$ then find the value of $l$ for a reccuring sequence $x_n$

Tags: real-analysis

I've proceeded the question like this:

Since limit $x_n$ exist, $x_n$ is convergent to l
So  $x_{n-1}, x_{n+1}$ is also convergent to l

It is given that
$x_{n+1}= αx_n+(1- α)x_{n-1}$
and $\lim_{x \to \infty} x_n=l$.
Therefore,$l=αl+(1-α)l$ , $l=l$

I'm stumped.. Any other approach or idea to solve this problem???

Given a real number $α \in (0, 1)$, define a sequence ${x_n}$ by the recurrence relation:$x_{n+1}= αx_n+(1- α)x_n-1,n \geq1$.If $\lim_{x \to \infty} x_n=l$ then find the value of $l$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $\lim_{x \to \infty} x_n=l$ does not imply $x_{n+1}$ or $x_{n-1}$ to be $l$ (if you take the limit they can converge to the same $l$)

Comment: by any chance is $x_1$ given?

Comment: Can you solve the relation for $x_n$?

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha$ represents a fraction in which you are dividing/sectioning the interval between the previous two points. The first few steps are depicted pictorially here:

[image: ...]

With a little more visualization, you should be able to convince yourself that $x_n$, for even $n$, is at a point between $x_0$ and $x_1$, with a ratio of $\alpha+\alpha(1-\alpha)^2+\alpha(1-\alpha)^4+\cdots$. Summing this as an infinite geometric series gives you the final answer of $\widetilde{\alpha}=\frac{\alpha}{1-(1-\alpha)^2}$, where $x_\infty=\ell$ is at a ratio of $\widetilde{\alpha}$ between $x_0$ and $x_1$, i.e. $\ell=(1-\widetilde{\alpha})x_0+\widetilde{\alpha}x_1$. I don't know of a more rigorous proof, although I've verified this answer numerically and it seems to work.